# Reading file - Match line with List

Tags: python, pandas, file, sys

I'm reading a file with Python that I only want to extract the lines that match with some contents. ' \
My problem is: if I pass only one string for the match I am able to do it (like the code below) '

```
import sys,os
import re
import pandas as pd

path = 'file'
sports = ['Sports', 'Nature']
keyword = 'Sports'
data = pd.DataFrame([])

with open(path) as auto:
  for line in auto:
    if keyword in line:
        print(line)
```

I pass a list I'm not able to retrieve any line:

```
with open(path) as auto:
  for line in auto:
    if any(x in errors for x in line):
        print(line)
```

Anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: If `keyword` is a `list` in the second snippet you showed. Then you want `if any(x in keyword for x in line.split()`. Because `for x in line` will iterate through each character over the `line`, where `line` is a `str`

Comment: @han solo , then in first instance, `if keyword in line`, it should also be iterating character by character?

Comment: @hacker315 No, because. It just checks, if `keywork` in `line`, like `Sports` in `"some line that has Sports in it"`. That's it

Comment: So, `if keyword in line` iterates word by word and `for x in line` iterates char by char, am i correct?

Comment: `if keyword in line`, just checks if the sequence `Sports` is anywhere in the `line`. You could check the difference between two in a `python` REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the difference, when you iterate over a `str` and `list`,

```
>>> keyword = ['sports', 'something else']
>>> line = "line that has a word sports in it"
>>> 'sports' in line
True
>>> any(x in keyword  for x in line.split()) # iterating over list
True
>>> any(x in keyword  for x in line) # iterating over each characters in an string
False
```

Comment: just a question imagine that in my file I don't have 'sports' but 'sports:' if I use the split() I will not be able to find the line. How can see all lines that contains 'sports' or 'something else'? Many thanks :)

Comment: change the check to `if any(x in line for x in keywords)` # where `keyword` is the `list` with content `['sports:', 'something else']` ? So, it will check if `sports:` or `something else` is in the line

Comment: But sometimes on my file I have 'Sports' or 'Sports:' or 'Sports-'... it depends :)

Comment: `if any(x.lower() in line.lower() for x in keywords)` or if you have `python3`, then use `.casefold()` instead `.lower()` # this should take care of that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative using list comprehension:

```
file = [line.lower() for line in open(path).readlines()]
required_line = [line for text in keyword for line in file if text.lower() in line]
```

Any by your method you have missed out something:

```
with open(path) as auto:
    for line in auto:
        if any(x for x in keyword for x in line):
            print(lines)
```

Comment: thanks! However with the second loop it brings all the lines in the document